# LYx 2.2. (Cannot view the file pdf)

Tags: errors, lyx

I get this error when trying to view the file:

```
The external program pdflatex finished with an error ... check the logs.
```

(I am using LyX 2.2.0  Windows 7)

Comment: The logs would help answer this question...

Comment: I looked for a log and found none!!!

Comment: Can you go to Document > LaTeX log?

Comment: This could be a bug. We would really like to know how to fix it. You can help us by sending a minimal example .lyx file and also the log that is in Document > LaTeX log (you can copy/paste to a file) to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org

Comment: I did not find any log.

Comment: I did not find any log. This error occurs even if the file is just one line of text (standard)!!